# Add column name to a DataFrame in for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

My dataset has no header, so no column name. The dataset begins with the information from the first line. I'd like to add column names.

**Edit** add DataSet:

```
30/10/2016 17:18:51 [13] 10-Full: L 1490; A 31; F 31; S 31; DL 0; SL 0; DT 5678
30/10/2016 17:18:51 [13] 00-Always: Returning 31 matches
30/10/2016 17:18:51 [13] 30-Normal: Query complete
30/10/2016 17:18:51 [13] 30-Normal: Request completed in 120 ms.
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 00-Always: Request from 120.0.0.1
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 00-Always: action=Query&Text=(("XXXXXX":*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/ObjectInfo/type+OR+"XXXXXX":*/DOCUMENT/.....
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 10-Full: L 2; A 1; F 1; S 0; DL 0; SL 0; DT 5373
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 00-Always: Returning 0 matches
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 30-Normal: Query complete
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 30-Normal: Request completed in 93 ms.
30/10/2016 17:19:20 [17] 00-Always: Request from 120.0.0.1
30/10/2016 17:19:20 [17] 00-Always: action=Query&Text=((PDF:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/XXXXX/type+AND+XXXXXX.......
30/10/2016 17:19:51 [19] 10-Full: L 255; A 0; F 0; S 0; DL 0; SL 0; DT 5021
30/10/2016 17:19:51 [19] 00-Always: Returning 0 matches
30/10/2016 17:19:51 [19] 30-Normal: Query complete
30/10/2016 17:19:51 [19] 30-Normal: Request completed in 29 ms.
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 00-Always: Request from 120.0.0.1
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 00-Always: action=Query&Tex(Image:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/ObjectInfo/type+AND+(
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 10-Full: L 13; A 0; F 0; S 0; DL 0; SL 0; DT 5235
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 00-Always: Returning 0 matches
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 30-Normal: Query complete
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 30-Normal: Request completed in 27 ms.
30/10/2016 17:21:09 [25] 00-Always: Request from 120.0.0.1
30/10/2016 17:21:09 [25] 00-Always: action=Query&Text=XXXXXX:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/ObjectIn
```

My Code:

```
for df in pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\s',  header=None, chunksize=6):
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
d = pd.DataFrame([df.loc[3,0], df.loc[3,1], ' '.join(df.loc[3,4:8]), ' '.join(df.loc[4,4:6]), ' '.join(df.loc[5,4:])])
d.T.to_csv('out.log', index=False, header=False, mode='a', sep=';')
```

Output from "My Code":

```
30/10/2016;17:19:12;Request completed in 93 ms.;Request from 120.0.0.1;action=Query&Text=((PDF:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/XXXXX....
30/10/2016;17:18:51;Request completed in 120 ms.;Request from 120.0.0.1;action=Query&Text=(("EOM.CompoundStory":*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTE....
30/10/2016;17:19:51;Request completed in 29 ms.;Request from 120.0.0.1;action=Query&Text=(Image:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/ObjectInfo/type+AND+((.....
30/10/2016;17:20:44;Request completed in 27 ms.;Request from 120.0.0.1;action=Query&Text=XXXXX:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONT....
```

Now I want to add in the first row a header like 1;2;3;4;5

My approach:

```
d.T.to_csv('out2.csv', index=False, header=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], mode='a', sep=';')
```

My Output:

```
1;2;3;4;5
07.11.2016;13:40:45;Request completed in 44 ms.;Request from 1.1.106 action=Query&Text=
1;2;3;4;5
07.11.2016;13:41:00;Request;completed in 37 ms.;Request from 1.1.106 ;action=Query&Text=   
1;2;3;4;5
07.11.2016;13:41:00;Request;completed in 32 ms.;Request from 1.1.106 ;action=Query&Text=
```

My excepted Output:

```
1;2;3;4;5
07.11.2016;13:40:45;Request completed in 44 ms.;Request from 1.1.106 action=Query&Text=
07.11.2016;13:41:00;Request;completed in 37 ms.;Request from 1.1.106 ;action=Query&Text=   
07.11.2016;13:41:00;Request;completed in 32 ms.;Request from 1.1.106 ;action=Query&Text=
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file `data.csv`?

Comment: What does the dataframe `d` look like?

Comment: Dataset has been added

Comment: Thanks, can you also add a sample of what your dataframe looks like once you carry out your initial formatting?

Comment: its now has been added :)

Comment: Whilst I see you already have a good answer, could you alternatively add your columns to your dataframe before you output it to csv? I.e. use the command:

    `d.columns = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

Then carry out your output to csv as before?

Comment: At the point operator at d, unfortunately no d.columns proposal is displayed ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try create empty `df` with header, write to `out.log` and then append data with no `header`:

```
cols = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
pd.DataFrame(columns=cols).to_csv('out.log', index=False, sep=';')

for df in pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\s+',  header=None, chunksize=6):
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df.fillna('', inplace=True)
    d = pd.DataFrame([df.loc[3,0], 
                      df.loc[3,1], 
                      ' '.join(df.loc[3,4:8]), 
                      ' '.join(df.loc[4,4:6]), 
                      ' '.join(df.loc[5,4:])])
    d.T.to_csv('out.log', index=False, header=False, mode='a', sep=';')
```

Comment: in the second line is this now: 0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0 and then comes the data

Comment: The first version of you had worked, with these 0.0 errors. Unfortunately, I have the following error:File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 846, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10364)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 880, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10845)
 pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:11257)
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 759, saw 18

Comment: It is really interesting. Can you send me youd file `data.csv'` to my email in my profile if not confidental data? what is separator in `read_csv`? `\s` or `s\+` ?

Comment: its now working, i had a type error.  its create a new .csv without 0.0! thanks for your offer :)